# Create UIImage from 2 UIImages and label

Tags: ios, uiimage, uilabel

I got one big `UIImage`. Over this `UIImage` i got one more, witch is actually a mask. And one more - i got `UILabel` over this mask! Witch is text for the picture.

I want to combine all this parts in one `UIImage` to save it to Camera Roll!

How should I do it?

UPD. How should i add `UITextView`?

i found:

```
[[myTextView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

But this method doesn't place myTextView on the right place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

create two `UIImage` objects and one `UILabel` objects then use `drawInRect:` method

```
//create image 1

UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];

//create image 2    

UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];

// create label

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50,50 )];

//set you label text

[label setText:@"Hello"];

// use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() to draw them on top of each other

//start drawing
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img1.size);

//draw image1

[img1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, img1.size.width, img1.size.height)];

//draw image2

[img2 drawInRect:CGRectMake((img1.size.width - img2.size.width) /2, (img1.size.height- img2.size.height)/2, img2.size.width, img2.size.height)];

//draw label

[label drawTextInRect:CGRectMake((img1.size.width - label.frame.size.width)/2, (img1.size.height - label.frame.size.height)/2, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height)];

//get the final image

UIImage *resultImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The `resultImage` which is `UIImage` contains all of your images and labels as one image.  After that you can save it where ever you want.

Hope helps...

Comment: how should i draw UITextView? there is not such function as "drawInRect" (